# How to subtract two timestamps with SQL command to get minutes

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the minutes from each workout from a column and add them up to get the total minutes completed.

I have the command line below:

```
SELECT sum(timefinished - timestarted) AS minutesBetween FROM workouts WHERE id = 'id'
```

My SQL database column is formatted as 'time'.

My result to this query is 5239. This is incorrect as the times I need to get a minute value between are:

**timefinished: 12:35:02 - timestarted 12:20:19 and timefinished: 12:55:07 - timestarted 12:17:51**

The result I am looking for is: 53

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [`TIMEDIFF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) should work in this case. You'll have to use it in conjunction with [`TIME_TO_SEC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec):

```
SELECT SUM(
    TIME_TO_SEC(
        TIMEDIFF(timefinished, timestarted)
    ) / 60) AS minutesBetween
FROM workouts
WHERE id = 'id';
```